# Typescript - Unhandled rejection TypeError: boss.SetBelongToClan is not a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, sequelize-typescript

I'm working with typescript and sequelize in an express app. I have a trouble when creating a type-safe interface for using function of associate. My Instance interface contains some property just look like

```
SetInstanceBelongTo : Sequelize.BelongsToSetAssociationMixin<ISqInstance,ISqInstance['primaryUniqueId']>;
```

And in App.ts I have this

```
private CheckConnectPosgrest(){
Database.instance.sequelize.authenticate().then(() =>{
  console.log("New structure Posgrest DB success in connect");
  //
  Database.instance.sequelize.sync().then(()=>{
    console.log("Synced database")
    //
    DataBase.GetSequelizeModelByModelInterface<ClanBossesInstance,ClanBossesAttribute>(ClanBosses).create({
      primaryUniqueId : "119",
        BossType : 1,
        IsOpen : false,
        CurrentHealth : 10000,
        ListDamage : "",
        TimeOpened : "2018-11-28 14:59:12.58",
        TimeClose : "2018-11-28 14:59:12.58"
    }).then(boss =>{
      boss.SetInstanceBelongTo({primaryUniqueId : "111"});
    })
  });
}).catch(error =>{
  console.log("New structure Posgrest DB fail in connect with error " + error);
})
}
```

And when run I get this Error :

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: boss.SetBelongToClan is not a function

I follow a tutorial from this link but modified an explicit interface to my abstract interface 
https://vivacitylabs.com/setup-typescript-sequelize/

Anyone can help me, please!

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that method on `boss` exist maybe that variable is `undefined` or `null`. Just log what `boss` is.